# Laravel: Set incoming request's GET param

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I want to append a new GET param to incoming request. How do I do this?

This is what I have tried and is not working,

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
  $_GET['key'] = getKeyForSession();
  Route::get('teams', 'TeamController@index');
});
```

Do I need to write a middleware for this? Even if I do, how do I set the GET param `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my question, there is [merge](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge) and [replace](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_replace) methods which we can use to modify input parameters

Example: `Input::merge(['key', 'value']);`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
  Input::merge(['key' => getKeyForSession()]);
  Route::get('teams', 'TeamController@index');
});
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a route parameter

```
Route::get('teams/{param}', 'TeamController@index');
```

if you want to make it optional by adding a question mark

Route::get('teams/{param?}', 'TeamController@index');

And you can get it in your controller

```
public function index($param)
{
    // your code....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found `Input::merge` method which does exactly what I want.